# Roblox - 'then' expected near 'local'

Tags: lua, roblox

My Roblox script is throwing an error and I'm not sure why. What does this error mean?

It says `line 7 [7: 0] 'then' expected near 'local'`

```
local name = "" -- put the name of the lemonade / hotdog stand owner here

local owner = game:GetService("Players")[name]

for i,v in pairs(game.ReplicatedStorage.API:GetChildren()) do
    if v:IsA("RemoteFunction")
        local A_1 = "lemonade_stand" -- change to hotdog_stand if its a hotdog stand
        local A_2 = owner
        v:InvokeServer(A_1, A_2)
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `then` as the **if-then** [syntax demands](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Conditional-Statements-in-Lua), and you also need another `end` to close the `for` loop:

```
local name = "" -- put the name of the lemonade / hotdog stand owner here

local owner = game:GetService("Players")[name]

for i,v in pairs(game.ReplicatedStorage.API:GetChildren()) do
  if v:IsA("RemoteFunction") then
    local A_1 = "lemonade_stand" -- change to hotdog_stand if its a hotdog stand
    local A_2 = owner
    v:InvokeServer(A_1, A_2)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you are lacking the requirements to make a functioning script.

When making conditions/statements, you must always put `then` after the condition.
Why? Think of syntax as a way of making the script make sense.
You are also missing an `end` at the end of your loop. Don't forget that!

Your script has been fixed below. Remember that whenever lua expects something, it's a syntax error.

```lua
local Name = '' 

for i,v in pairs(game.ReplicatedStorage.API:GetChildren()) do 
    if v:IsA("RemoteFunction") then 
        v:InvokeServer('lemonade_stand', game.Players[Name]) -- or you could do game.Players.LocalPlayer[PlayerName], which is easier.  
    end 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add "then" after if v:IsA('RemoteEvent').
Conditional statements in Lua always start like this

```
local yourcondition = true

if yourcondition then
    print("yourcondition is true!")
end
```

This was kind of a silly mistake, but you should always look at the errors Roblox shows before typing your question here. This could've been very easily solved using the Output window. (View -> Output) This is just how the syntax works. Take the LUA interpreter as your English teacher. Your teacher will tell you that you made a mistake if you did not do what the syntax of English wants.

Answer (score 0):

```
    local name = "" -- put the name of the lemonade / hotdog stand owner here

    local owner = game:GetService("Players")[name]

    for i,v in pairs(game.ReplicatedStorage.API:GetChildren()) do
        if v:IsA("RemoteFunction") then
            local A_1 = "lemonade_stand" -- change to hotdog_stand if its a hotdog stand
            local A_2 = owner
            v:InvokeServer(A_1, A_2)
        end
    end
```

At the "if v:IsA("RemoteFunction")" you forgot to put "then" after it.
And you forgot one "end" at the last line.